# Error: Function 'call' at (1) has no implicit type

Tags: fortran

I am trying to get a root of a function using bisection method, But I am getting this error:

```
    if (call (f(a))==0 .or. call (f(a))<=error) then
                            1
Error: Function 'call' at (1) has no implicit type
```

I don´t know how to solve the problem.

```
program biseccion
real::a,b,raiz 
print*,"Escribar el valor a del intervalor[a,b]"
read*,a
print*,"Escribar el valor b del intervalor[a,b]"
read*,b
call bis(a,b,raiz)
print*,raiz

Contains
function f(x) result(f_result)
    real,intent(in)::x
    real::f_result
    f_result=x**(3)+2*x**(2)+10*x-20 !Escribir la funcion
end function f    

subroutine bis(a,b,raiz)
real,intent(in)::a,b
real,intent(out)::raiz
real,parameter::error=epsilon(error)
do
    if (call (f(a))==0 .or. call (f(a))<=error) then
        raiz=call(f(a))
        exit
    else if (call (f(b))==0 .or. call (f(b))<=error) then
        raiz=call (f(b)) 
    else if (call (f(a)) <0 .and. call (f(b))>0) then
        if (call (f(a/2)) <0) then
            a=a/2
        else 
            b=b/2
        end if
    else if (call (f(a)) >0 .and. call (f(b))<0 ) then
        if (call (f(a/2)) >0) then
            a=a/2
        else
            b=b/2
        end if
    end if
end do
end subroutine bis
end program biseccion
```

Comment: Welcome, I suggest taking the Welcome [tour]. Please use tag [tag:fortran] for all Fortran questions. You can add a specific tag if your question is version-specific.

Answer (score 2):

The `call` statement cannot be used in an expression. Only as a separate statement.

However `f()` is a function, it is not invoked using the `call` statement but only using the function name.

```
  if (f(a)==0 .or. f(a)<=error) then
    raiz = f(a)
```

and so on.